# Replacing comma with dot rounds the value and removes decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to change a comma (,) with a dot (.) in a row with values, but when doing so, the value is rounded with only two decimals.

So the value `[LineAmount]` normally returns, as an example: "`1389,344`"

But when doing `REPLACE([LineAmount], ',', '.')` the value changes to "`1389.34`"

This only happens if the value has 3 decimals, with 2 or 1, the `REPLACE` is done correctly.

What am I missing? I tried converting the value to varchar or to decimal before the `REPLACE`, but the same happens.

I only need to change the comma with a dot, nothing else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pust a full [mre]. I can't replicate your problem. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07675d190a073dd8b27ab0be528d8235). Seems the real problem, however, is you're storing numeric data as strings.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: @jarlh Valid question. Guessing the datatype of the column is decimal(x,2).

Comment: *"Guessing the datatype of the column is decimal(x,2)"* If it were, @Dr.Casual , it could never have the value `'1389,344'`.

Comment: @Larnu He's not saying that he's writing to the same table (guessing he's not). Else I'm not really clear on what the intention is and how it would happen :D

Comment: Column data type is float.

Comment: I really can't post an example, there's nothing else.
Its just a select trying to change comma to dot.

Comment: `float` values don't have commas; there's your first problem. `REPLACE({FloatValue},',','.')` isn't going to do anything (meaningful). Next, `float` is an imprecise data type, so you've actually stated your happy with that data loss by using that type. 2 lessons; 1 numerical data types don't have formatting so you can't replace a comma with a period. 2. don't use `float` if you want precise values and *don't* want to suffer rounding issues like this.

Comment: @Nanaki why can't you post an example? Declare a variable of type float, set it to a value that causes this issue, and use your select against the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The *real* problem is 2 fold:

1. You think that numerical data types have format data; they don't.
2. You are using a floating point data type and then are "upset" when it loses precision, despite that when you defined the value as a `float` you said you're happy with such behaviour.

The solution, therefore, is simple, use a `decimal`/`numeric` data type for the storage your data, so it doesn't suffer rounding issues. Then, if you need formatting on the value, do that in the presentation layer, *not* the RDBMS. `REPLACE({Numerical Data Type},',','.')` isn't going to do anything meaningful as numerical data types *aren't* strings; they don't work like them.

How you achieve the formatting in your presentation layer is a completely different question, as that depends on the tools you are using to build said presentation layer.

Comment: The thing is this database is really old and not setup by me, so the datatype flotat cannot be changed now. That's why I was looking for a workarround or a solution in order to achieve it. If SQL Server cannot do that for me, I'll try to do in using in the presentation layer as you said.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer though, @Nanaki . Point 1 still stands, numerical data doesn't have a format so replacing the commas make no sense; it doesn't have any.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand, as I am no SQL expert, but changing it to string also removes values, why is that?

24859,296 > float / 
24859.3 > nvarchar

Comment: Welcome to using imprecise data types, @Nanaki . Again, *"when you defined the value as a `float` you said you're happy with such behaviour."*